What is the relation of two types Airy equation?
Consider the Airy equation
$$u_t +u_{xxx}=0,$$
for $u:[0, \infty)\times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}.$
i) Derive an equation for the Fourier transform of $u.$
ii) Use Fourier analysis to show that $u$ can be expressed in terms of solutions of ordinary differential equation
$$\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0$$
and use this observation to derive an explicit solution for $u.$
I am done with i) and I have the equation for the Fourier transform of $u$ is
$$\hat{u}_t(\xi,t)-i8\pi^3\xi^3\hat{u}(\xi,t)=0.$$
Therefore, multiply both sides by $e^{-i8\pi^3\xi^3t}$ then take the integral, we end up
$$\hat{u}(\xi,t)=\cos(8\pi^3\xi^3t)\hat{u}(0,t)+i\sin(8\pi^3\xi^3t)\hat{u}(0,t)$$
So now I don't know what should I do next, I don't know how to relate the solution of the original problem with $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0.$
When I searched Airy equation, it's always about $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0$ equation and I also did not see the relation between $$u_t +u_{xxx}=0$$ and $\dfrac{d^2y}{dx^2}-xy=0.$
Could you please give me any hints? Thank you very much.

If you write $\tilde{u}(k,t)=\tilde{u_0}(k)e^{ik^3t}$ (equivalent to what you have already done), then note that the Fourier transform of the solution to the equation $y''(x)-xy(x)=0$ can be written as $\tilde{y}(k)=e^{ik^3/3}$, we can see that $u$ can be written as a convolution $u(x,t)\propto\int dx' \ u_0(x')G(x-x')$, where $G(x)=y(x/\sqrt[3]{3t})$. So the Airy functions are essentially the Green's functions of your first equation. You'd need to work out some of the technical details...

@Sal Thank you very much. I wrote it down and I can see the relationship between them. I am trying to understand the solution $u(x,t)$ as the convolution you provided.

No problem. It's a type of convolution because $\tilde{u}=\tilde{u}_0e^{ik^3t}$ so $u(x,t)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\tilde{u}_0(k) \ \tilde{y}(k))$ where $\mathcal{F}^{-1}$ is the inverse Fourier transform, then use the convolution property

I am done with the proof. Thank you ^^

Glad to help :)
